# Can I combine between ng-zorro-antd and ng-zorro-antd-mobile in one design?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I'm building an application using Angular, and I want to design a responsive website that works on both (Web) and (Mobile). I know that `ng-zorro-antd` provides responsive layout , but it's not always compatible with the `Mobile`.

My Question is: Can I combine both of `ng-zorro-antd` and `ng-zorro-antd-mobile`  in the same application in order to display the components of `ng-zorro-antd-mobile` dynamically when I change the device to mobile "using an emulated for instance Chrome ? and to reset it to be the normal layout by `ng-zorro-antd` ? or this is overloading in the design and the code size?

If not, How Can I design a website that works on both devices?

Thanks

Comment: Actual question, i have tried `ng add ng-zorro-antd` and then `ng add ng-zorro-antd-mobile` build was ok, but any requests fail with error:

`[Nest] 14369   - 07/29/2021, 3:41:02 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] undefined:1:13334: property missing ':' +55435ms
Error: undefined:1:13334: property missing ':'
    at error
    at declaration
    at declarations 
    at rule
    at rules
    at stylesheet
    at Object.parse$1 [as parse]
    at parseStylesheet
    at CrittersExtended.processStyle
`

Before I execute `ng add ng-zorro-antd-mobile` it works fine!